# Ubuntu bootloader suddenly become unaccessible

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader

I had dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode along side windows 10 on the same SSD drive. Everything was working for a month, and suddenly now the bootloader is not visible. On turning the machine on, it directly boots to Windows 10.

Comment: Windows does updates and resets itself to first in boot order? And Windows may turn fast start up back on, so you cannot boot Windows from Ubuntu. Can you still boot Windows from UEFI boot menu? Post this above: `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Comment: @oldfred, it directly boots to Windows before showing the grub. So I cannot execute the above command.

Comment: You should be able to change boot order in UEFI. But boot Ubuntu live installer to run efibootmgr commands. What brand/model system. Some only want to boot Windows and need work arounds. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: In the boot order menu, or couldn't find grub, there was just the windows bootloader. And secure boot was turned on. So just used Ubuntu live USB, to reinstall grub. And the problem is solved. Thanks.